# SQL Insert statement doesn't generate Id automatically

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently learning Hibernate, and I plan to use a PreparedStatement to insert a record into the database. However, it seems that the insert query won't automatically generate a UUID for my record.

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user_details")
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class User extends Base {

    @NonNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;
```

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;
}
```

DaoImplementation

```
    private static final String SAVE_USER = "INSERT INTO user_details(user_name) VALUES(?)";


@Override
    public UserDto saveUser(User user) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            connection = source.getConnection();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SAVE_USER);
            ps.setString(1, user.getUserName());

            try {
                ps.execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to save user to db");
            }
            return findUserByName(user.getUserName());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                closeAll(resultSet, ps, connection);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Trying to understand why it doesn't not automatically generate id

Comment: If you are using JPA don't use JDBC, just create your object and let JPA store it. Learning JPA doesn't mean define entities then forget about JPA.

Comment: use this : 
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing technologies here in a bad way.

This configuration

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
```

Will cause JPA to generate a new UUID and set the `id` of your entity to it when persisting an entity *using JPA*.

But you are not using JPA to persist your entity.
You are using JDBC, which knows nothing about JPA annotations.

If you use `EntityManager.persist` with your entity or (since you tagged the question [spring-data-jdbc](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jdbc)) `CrudRepository.save`, the id of the entity should get set as expected.

Comment: Thank you if I change the annotation to(down below), it will generate an id when I use jdbc. 
Is this also handled by jpa?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;
```

Comment: JPA will expect the id column to be an identity/autoincrement column. I'm not sure if a sequence default will work as well. Worth a try.